# How to configure NHibernate SessionFactory in code

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new to NHibernate and I'm trying to configure it based on the book 'Learning NHibernate 4'. However, I'm stuck with how to configure it. I have a class called `Connection` but when I try to use it, NHibernate tells me it can't find 'HbmMapping'.

```
class Connection
    {
        public Connection() 
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {
                x.Dialect<PostgreSQLDialect>();
                x.Driver<NpgsqlDriver>();
                x.ConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1; Port=5433; User Id=smartwarehouse; Password=$smart#2018;Database=warehouse;";
                x.ConnectionReleaseMode = ConnectionReleaseMode.OnClose;
                x.LogSqlInConsole = true;
                x.LogFormattedSql = true;


            }).AddMapping(GetMappings());

        }
          // here is Hbm dosn't find from library
     private HbmMapping GetMappings() 
        {



        }
    }
```

[image]

it gives me other two options to use like here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-configuration) is probably a better resource for this issue. You typically tell it where your mappings are at an assembly level...

```
.AddFromAssemblyOf<YourEntity>();
```

...so that when you add/remove mappings, you don't need to change your code.

For example, my `SessionProvider` has a bit like this:

```
Config = new NHibernateConfig();
Config.Configure(); // read config default style

Fluently
     .Configure(Config)
     .Mappings(
         m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>()
...
```

I don't have `.hbm` files as I use derivatives of `ClassMap`. However, as long as the type you specify in the `AddFromAssemblyOf` method is in the same assembly as your `.hbm` files, then it should work. So something like:

```
Fluently
    .Configure(Config)
    .Mappings(
        m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ATypeInYourMappingAssembly>()
```

Comment: Make sure your .hbm files are embedded resources too!

Comment: how I can embedde in programatically with my mappings classes

Comment: Set the 'Build Action' on the `.hbm` files' properties.

Comment: where should I write down .AddFromAssemblyOf<Entity> please tell me